# No route matches [POST] "/knock/user_token"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, access-token

I'm currently using the JWT authentication for Rails API from this link:
https://github.com/nsarno/knock
and I followed her instruction carefully. However, I still cannot login with the username and password I just registered. I can register with no error, and show me this message:

```
Started POST "/users" for ::1 at 2016-12-20 22:28:32 -0500
Processing by UsersController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"user"=>{"email"=>"xxx@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}}
   (0.4ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.8ms)  INSERT INTO "users" ("email", "password_digest", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "id"  [["email", "zsy2053@gmail.com"], ["password_digest", "$2a$10$1UAPAV92l.pHhbT.L3BvfOP7ieuy9yU2cdWdwy9VsVnTHjaRECB0W"], ["created_at", 2016-12-21 03:28:32 UTC], ["updated_at", 2016-12-21 03:28:32 UTC]]
   (28.7ms)  COMMIT
[active_model_serializers] Rendered ActiveModel::Serializer::Null with Hash (1.42ms)
Completed 200 OK in 162ms (Views: 21.2ms | ActiveRecord: 34.3ms)
```

However, I got this error if I just login with the user name and password I registered:

```
Started POST "/knock/user_token" for ::1 at 2016-12-20 22:29:02 -0500

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [POST] "/knock/user_token"):
```

Here is the routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :cars
  get '/users/current-user', to: "current_user#show"
  resources :users
  mount Knock::Engine => "/knock"
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
end
```

Here is the output of rake routes | grep knock

```
            knock        /knock                        Knock::Engine
auth_token POST /auth_token(.:format) knock/auth_token#create
```

Here is the configuration of routers.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  post 'user_token' => 'user_token#create'
  resources :cars
  get '/users/current-user', to: "current_user#show"
  resources :users
  mount Knock::Engine => "/knock"
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
end
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Please post `routes.rb`.

Comment: @31piy posted already. I just followed her instruction

Comment: Please post output of `rake routes | grep knock`

Comment: @unkmas posted already

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have read docs for this gem.

There is no such route by default. When you installing this gem, you should generate token controller for your application:

`rails generate knock:token_controller user`

Output of this command:

```
create  app/controllers/user_token_controller.rb
route  post 'user_token' => 'user_token#create'
```

As you can see, token controller was created, and also route for it.

Comment: I tried, and I can generate the token_controller. But I got the same error

Comment: @D.Kenny This is weird. Add your new routes.rb please.

Comment: @D.Kenny now you have '/user_token' route, while trying to access '/knock/user_token', which does not exists. Access '/user_token' and it should work :) Happy New Year too :)